# elsarticle class generating errors with author block

Tags: pdftex, elsarticle

I am using the elsarticle class and trying to compile a document with TeX Live 2014.  The frontmatter section generates the same error every time, and I am out of ideas how to correct it.  The front matter is taken directly from the example from the elsarticle documentation

```
\begin{frontmatter}
 \title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1,t2}}
 \tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
 \tnotetext[t2]{The second title footnote which is  
    longer than the first one and with an intention to fill
    in up more than one line while formatting.} 

 \author[rvt]{C.V.~Radhakrishnan\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}}
 \ead{cvr@river-valley.com}

 \author[rvt,focal]{C.V.~Rajagopal\fnref{fn2}}
 \ead{cvr3@river-valley.com}

 \author[saya]{G.S. Krishna\corref{cor2}\fnref{fn1,fn3}}
 \ead[url]{http://www.sayahna.org}

 \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
 \cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author}
 \fntext[fn1]{This is the specimen author footnote.}
 \fntext[fn2]{Another author footnote, but a little more longer.}
 \fntext[fn3]{Yet another author footnote. Indeed, you can have
    any number of author footnotes.}

 \address[rvt]{River Valley Technologies, River Valley Campus,
    Mepukada, Malayinkil, Trivandrum 695571, India}
 \address[focal]{Focal Image (India) Pvt Ltd., River Valley Campus,
    Mepukada, Malayinkil, Trivandrum 695571, India}
 \address[saya]{JWRA 34, Jagathy, Trivandrum 695014, India}
\end{frontmatter}
```

When I compile with pdflatex, the following error is generated:

```
! Argument of \@author has an extra }.
<inserted text>
            \par
l.113 ...f\AB@author{\noexpand\AB@blk@and\@author}

?
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@author was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.113 ...f\AB@author{\noexpand\AB@blk@and\@author}
```

I can add the full log file if that is helpful, but I thought it might be excessive.

Answer (score 7):

The problem was that I was loading the authblk package in the preamble, and this evidently clashed with elsarticle's handling of the author block.

Comment: What you also learn from this, hopefully, is that your current question provides very little detail in terms of the [`authblk` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) that you apparently loaded. For future reference, please see how to create what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).