# Authors input affil

Tags: elsarticle, journal-publishing, affiliation

I am writing the title and the authors of my article, but when I compile the document the PDF generated only shows the title.

Could anyone help me to fix it?

Thank you!

here is the preamble and the title with the authors and theirs affilations

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} 
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}
\renewcommand\Authands{ and }

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{blablabla}

\author[1]{ Mart\'in Torres}
\author[1]{Jorge Castiglioni}
\author[1]{Patrice Portugau}
\author[2]{Manuela Morales Demarco}
\author[2]{Bruno Conti}
\author[2]{Pablo Gristo}
\author[3]{Luis Yerm\'an}
\author[3]{Leopoldo Suescun}
\author[1]{Andr\'es Cu\~na}

\affil[1]{Area de Fisicoqu\'imica, DETEMA, Facultad de Qu\'imica, Universidad de la Rep\'ublica, Uruguay}
\affil[2]{Gerencia de Exploraci\'on y Producci\'on, Administraci\'on Nacional de Combustibles, Alcohol y Portland, Uruguay}
\affil[3]{School of Civil Engineering, University of Queensland, Brisbane, Australia}
\affil[4]{Laboratorio de Cristalograf\'ia, Qu\'imica del Estado S\'olido y Materiales, Area de F\'isica, DETEMA, Facultad de Qu\'imica – Universidad de la Rep\'ublica, Uruguay}

\end{document}
```

when i compile, the error that the program shows is:

```
Paragraph ended before \@author was complete. ...f\AB@author{\noexpand\AB@blk@and\@author} 
Argument of \@author has an extra }. ...f\AB@author{\noexpand\AB@blk@and\@author}
```

Comment: The code example is not complete (e.g., no `\end{document}` and no `\maketitle` or similar). This makes it difficult for us to reproduce the problem. Also, there are many `\usepackage`s that are unrelated to the problem, which makes it difficult for us to isolate the problem. Try to complete the document and to remove as many packages as you can, to end up with a minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: You also load several packages multiple times (e.g. `multirow`, `graphicx`, `makecell`, `caption`, `pgfplots`)

Comment: And, of course, welcome to the site :)

Comment: i put only the initial part of the document, the article is too long to show all here.  The problem is only when i compile , in the PDF didn't appear the authors, only the title. I finished the document with \end{document} for example

Comment: I corrected the packages that appear multiple times, thank you bmv. however, this didn't fix the problem of the authors.

Comment: The idea is to make a minimal but complete example that shows the problem (see the first example in my answer as illustration). When asking a question, you can remove all packages from the preamble as long as the problem is still present, because in that case such a package is not relevant for the question. Moreover, when you remove a package and the problem disappears, you know that this package has caused the problem and you can search more easily for a solution or ask a better question here. (note that in this case there was a different problem, but the strategy in general is useful)

Comment: Of course, if you want to modify the output of the current solution, you are very welcome to ask a follow-up question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `elsarticle` class is not compatile with the `authblk` package (also noted in [elsarticle class generating errors with author block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283477/elsarticle-class-generating-errors-with-author-block)).

The following minimal working example shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{blablabla}
\author[1]{Mart\'in Torres}
\author[1]{Jorge Castiglioni}
\author[1]{Patrice Portugau}
\author[2]{Manuela Morales Demarco}
\author[2]{Bruno Conti}
\author[2]{Pablo Gristo}
\author[3]{Luis Yerm\'an}
\author[3]{Leopoldo Suescun}
\author[1]{Andr\'es Cu\~na}
\affil[1]{Area de Fisicoqu\'imica, DETEMA, Facultad de Qu\'imica, Universidad de la Rep\'ublica, Uruguay}
\affil[2]{Gerencia de Exploraci\'on y Producci\'on, Administraci\'on Nacional de Combustibles, Alcohol y Portland, Uruguay}
\affil[3]{School of Civil Engineering, University of Queensland, Brisbane, Australia}
\affil[4]{Laboratorio de Cristalograf\'ia, Qu\'imica del Estado S\'olido y Materiales, Area de F\'isica, DETEMA, Facultad de Qu\'imica – Universidad de la Rep\'ublica, Uruguay}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

This results in the error `! Argument of \@author has an extra }.`.

However, `elsarticle` has some built-in features that provide output similar to `authblk`. Therefore, a possible solution is to use these features and not use `authblk` at all. Note that, if you are submitting a paper to Elsevier, you are most likely not allowed to change the front matter layout anyway.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{blablabla}
\author[1]{Mart\'in Torres}
\author[1]{Jorge Castiglioni}
\author[1]{Patrice Portugau}
\author[2]{Manuela Morales Demarco}
\author[2]{Bruno Conti}
\author[2]{Pablo Gristo}
\author[3]{Luis Yerm\'an}
\author[3]{Leopoldo Suescun}
\author[1]{Andr\'es Cu\~na}
\address[1]{Area de Fisicoqu\'imica, DETEMA, Facultad de Qu\'imica, Universidad de la Rep\'ublica, Uruguay}
\address[2]{Gerencia de Exploraci\'on y Producci\'on, Administraci\'on Nacional de Combustibles, Alcohol y Portland, Uruguay}
\address[3]{School of Civil Engineering, University of Queensland, Brisbane, Australia}
\address[4]{Laboratorio de Cristalograf\'ia, Qu\'imica del Estado S\'olido y Materiales, Area de F\'isica, DETEMA, Facultad de Qu\'imica – Universidad de la Rep\'ublica, Uruguay}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Note that `affil` has changed to `address`. Result:

[image]